# Python program "genipe" - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'

Tags: python, typeerror, normalize

I am trying to run the program genipe to do some genome-wide survival analysis. I have installed genipe and all the relevant directories. However, when I go to run the program I get the error:

"TypeError: _ *init* _() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'"

I haven't edited any of the genipe scripts and I have run genipe with no issues on a different server so I am not sure what is going wrong! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Caragh

Edit:
I am using python version 3.6.1

Traceback as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 965, in process_impute2_site
    use_ml=site_info.use_ml,
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 1048, in fit_cox
    cf = CoxPHFitter(alpha=0.95, tie_method="Efron", normalize=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 811, in compute_statistics
    for result in pool.map(process_impute2_site, sites_to_process):
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'

[2017-05-31 14:18:53 ERROR] __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 965, in process_impute2_site
    use_ml=site_info.use_ml,
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 1048, in fit_cox
    cf = CoxPHFitter(alpha=0.95, tie_method="Efron", normalize=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/bin/imputed-stats", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 161, in main
    options=args,
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 811, in compute_statistics
    for result in pool.map(process_impute2_site, sites_to_process):
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/users/k1640238/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'
```

Comment: To be able to fix this, really the entire traceback and your Python version is needed.

Comment: I have edited the question to include traceback and version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [lifeline changelog](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0100) this keyword argument has been removed from this particular function. Lifeline is a package which contains this particular function and is [used by genipe](https://github.com/pgxcentre/genipe/blob/master/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py#L40).

You can either install previous version of lifeline by yourself and see if that will help or wait for updates in genipe library.

Looking at further errors from your comments, it seems like [this is problematic code](https://github.com/pgxcentre/genipe/blob/master/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py#L46-L52). You are trying to use `dmatrices` but it seems like it is not defined. Probably because mentioned `try/catch` block couldn't find `statsmodel` installed and therefore `patsy` wasn't imported either.

Try to install few more packages manually, starting with

- [statsmodel](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html)
- [patsy](https://github.com/pydata/patsy)

and see if you will get any errors then...

Comment: Great, thanks errata, I'll try installing a previous version this evening and see if that works.

Comment: I've reverted back to a previous version of lifelines. However am still having a similar issue. I have installed all the package versions that are specified in the genipe instructions.

Comment: ERROR: test_fit_cox_interaction_snp1 (genipe.tests.test_imputed_stats.TestImputedStatsCox)
Tests the 'fit_cox' function with interaction, first SNP.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tests/test_imputed_stats.py", line 866, in test_fit_cox_interaction_snp1
    formula=formula,
  File "/miniconda/envs/genipe_pyvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genipe/tools/imputed_stats.py", line 1128, in fit_cox
    y, X = dmatrices(formula, data=data, return_type="dataframe")
NameError: name 'dmatrices' is not defined

Comment: @Caragh Updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

See errata's answer above, I was using the wrong versions of some of the dependancies, but even with that the program was still giving me errors. However when I reverted to python 3.4, the program worked.